# Storing and downloading files from Redis in Django Celery Queue

Tags: django, redis, celery

I'm zipping a large number of files in my app, which leads to problems with performance. So now I've decided to zip files in a separate queue, store results in Redis and make available to user as soon as the process is done. I'm storing data in Redis to make it faster, and because I don't need files to be stored on server hard drive.

Here is my task.py:

```
@shared_task
def zip_files(filenames, key):
  compression = zipfile.ZIP_STORED
  s = BytesIO()
  zf = zipfile.ZipFile(s, mode="w")
  for fpath in filenames:
      fdir, fname = os.path.split(fpath)
      zf.write(fpath, fname, compress_type=compression)
  zf.close()
  caches['redis'].set(hash_key, {'file':s.getvalue()})
  return hash_key
```

And then here is my simple download view:

```
def folder_cache(request, folder_hash):
   cache_data = caches['redis'].get(folder_hash)
   if cache_data:
      response = FileResponse(cache_data['file'], content_type="application/x-zip-compressed")
      response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=hello.zip' 
      response['Content-Length'] = len(cache_data['file'])
      return response
  return HttpResponse("Cache expired.")
```

Problem is that I can only download a part of the file, then the download is stopped by "Network connection was lost" message. The downloaded file seems to contain a set of numbers (not binary data). But I don't know, maybe I use FileResponse wrong? Or I need to serialize data before / after putting it to Redis cache?

I also tried same code in shell, it works when I use fopen and write data from Redis cache directly to server hard drive.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found out that I only had to wrap file data into ContentFile class. So here is the latest working code:

```
def folder_cache(request, folder_hash):
    cache_data = caches['redis'].get(folder_hash)
    if cache_data:
        if (cache_data['status'] == 'complete'):
            ...
            response = FileResponse(ContentFile(cache_data['file']), content_type="application/x-zip-compressed")
            response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename={}'.format(filename)
            response['Content-Length'] = len(cache_data['file'])
            return response
```